# What is a difference between using a .poll() & .recv() methods in ZeroMQ?

Tags: java, zeromq

In ZeroMQ `PUB/SUB` mode tutorial, there is a **`.poll()`** method:

```
ZMQ.Poller items = new ZMQ.Poller (1);
while (!Thread.currentThread ().isInterrupted ()) {
        byte[] message;
        items.poll();

        if (items.pollin(0)) {
            message = subscriber.recv(0);
            System.out.println("received message:" + message);
        }
 }
```

This method lets you check the status of a connection. But it seems that the `.poll()` method is "another" `.recv()` without timeout!?

Both of them would stick thread/program until data is received.

Using a `.poll()` just lets a program stuck at `.poll()` instead of `.recv()`!?

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### ZeroMQ has introduced two, very different mechanics here:

---

### **`.recv()`** method:

The **`.recv( <aSocketAccessPointINSTANCE>, <ZMQ_DONTWAIT_FLAG> )`** is a method, that **may**, but **need not** block on an attempt to receive `aSocketAccessPoint`-delivered message into the hands of the kind user for further processing.

As syntax enforces, coder has to specify, from which ZeroMQ Scalable Formal Communication Archetype's Access Point the method ought try to pick a next FIFO message or a part of a multi-part message.

ZeroMQ  ensures atomic delivery of messages: peers shall receive either all message parts of a message or none at all. The total number of message parts is unlimited except by available memory.

An application that processes multi-part messages must use and further investigate the **`ZMQ_RCVMORE`** in a **`zmq_getsockopt(3)`** option after calling `zmq_recvmsg()` to determine, if there are further parts to receive.

---

### **`.poll()`** method is different ( while it may "shortcut" some logic ):

Before one can use a `.poll()` method, there are some duties to setup first the details for the `.Poller()` instance behaviour.

ZeroMQ provides this as a mechanism for multiplexing more and many input/output events over a set of Access Points ( containing both ZeroMQ smart-sockets and ( in more recent API versions ) also standard, plain O/S-sockets. This mechanism mirrors the standard sockets' `poll()` system call.

`Poller()` instance can be instructed to `.poll()` one or several "local" Access Points to ask them about their internal state and can receive **{ zero | one | more }**-answers, depending on the call-setup, actual state of the queried resources and whether a timeout has run off, before any specified event has arrived onto the "local" side of the listed Access Points at all.

The ZeroMQ original API defines for this:

```
int zmq_poll ( zmq_pollitem_t *items, int nitems, long timeout );
```

whereas the respective language bindings may re-wrap this API into some sort of a higher level helper method ( not to have manually declare how many records `nitems` one tries to pass in `*items` once the sizing of the MUX-events object is known at the runtime, before the low-level API is going to be called -- so re-check the ZeroMQ binding documentation for the exact syntax, exposed to user-code ).

As noted in the O/P, given a `.poll()` was called with the value of `timeout == -1`, having just a single Access Point in the `*items`, the `.poll()` shall block indefinitely until a requested event has occurred on the specified `zmq_pollitem_t` set for `{ ZMQ_POLLIN }`, so here, the blocking the user-code effectively mirrors what would `.recv()` do at that very place. Yet, the respective mechanics are way different.

Answer (score 2):

`recv()` waits for messages from just 1 ZeroMQ socket, while `poll()` lets you wait for messages from many ZeroMQ sockets.

The `Poller` also lets you easily specify a timeout when waiting for messages.

Note, your code seems to miss the needed calls to
`items.register( subscriber, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN );`